# React Ag-grid Loading overlay prop

Tags: reactjs, overlay, loading, ag-grid-react

I am making a data grid with ag-grid, and I found how to set my loading overlay but for some reason I can only control it with the gridApi.showLoadingOverlay() function, and I did find this prop 'suppressLoadingOverlay', but for some reason it's not working, it's not showing the overlay when set to false or true for that matter. Does anyone know if I got the wrong prop or if there is some other prop that I can use to control the overlay ?

Comment: 'I can only control it with the gridApi.showLoadingOverlay()'. Do you want to hide it also or something? If so, call `gridApi.hideOverlay()`. Setting `suppressLoadingOverlay` to true will prevent the loading overlay from showing so I think it works as intended